# CakePHP - Maintaining User Sessions

Tags: php, cakephp

Can anyone point to some examples on how to maintain user sessions in CakePHP. I guess, I need examples where user will login to the system and can only view his own stuff etc!

Comment: Have you tried to follow [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1250/Authentication)? If so, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can get logged in user session as:

```
$userIDFromSession = $this->Session->read("Auth.User.id");

//check manual for more info on sessions: http://book.cakephp.org
```

Comment: You should use `$this->Auth->user('id')` for this instead.